# Way to compare array key & replace value if found (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am trying to make an php application, but i am having some trouble with arrays
Actually,
I m trying to compare array key & if found replace its value & merge whole array into one.

For example

Array **ONE**-

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
               (
                [label] => July 20 2020
                [y] => 3
               )
        [1] => Array
               (
                [label] => July 18 2020
                [y] => 1
               )
    )
```

Array **TWO**-

```
  Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                   (
                    [label] => July 18 2020
                    [y] => 0
                   )
            [1] => Array
                   (
                    [label] => July 19 2020
                    [y] => 0
                   )
            [2] => Array
                   (
                    [label] => July 20 2020
                    [y] => 0
                   )
            [3] => Array
                   (
                    [label] => July 21 2020
                    [y] => 0
                   )
        )
```

**To
desired output array**

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                       (
                        [label] => July 18 2020
                        [y] => 1
                       )
                [1] => Array
                       (
                        [label] => July 19 2020
                        [y] => 0
                       )
                [2] => Array
                       (
                        [label] => July 20 2020
                        [y] => 3
                       )
                [3] => Array
                       (
                        [label] => July 21 2020
                        [y] => 0
                       )
            )
```

I have tried

`array_merge($arrayone, $arraytwo)`;

but it doesn't work.
Is it possible to get the desired output ?

This is how array looks like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT0TW.jpg
Please share your thoughts on this.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your arrays, I do not think there is a smart way to do it, but this should work :

```
    <?php
$datesArray = [
    [
        'label' => 'July 18 2020',
        'y'     => 0,
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'July 19 2020',
        'y'     => 0,
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'July 20 2020',
        'y'     => 0,
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'July 21 2020',
        'y'     => 0,
    ],
];

$valuesArray = [
    [
        'label' => 'July 20 2020',
        'y'     => 3,
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'July 18 2020',
        'y'     => 1,
    ],
];

foreach($datesArray as &$dateArray) {
    foreach($valuesArray as $valueArray) {
        // use ?? if php version allows it, else do isset($valueArray['label']) ? $valueArray['label'] : null;
        $currentLabel = $valueArray['label'] ?? null; 
        if ($currentLabel === $dateArray['label']) {
            $dateArray['y'] = $valueArray['y'] ?? 0;
        }
    }
}

print_r($datesArray);
return $datesArray;
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => July 18 2020
            [y] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => July 19 2020
            [y] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => July 20 2020
            [y] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => July 21 2020
            [y] => 0
        )

)
```

This will take quadratic time, if you need something faster you will have to change the indices of your arrays to make a faster lookup.

[snippet](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08a54eefe48ed213cd023bad7a31005585b32a0c)

Comment: Hello, you mean there is no return ? I have added return to the end of the script, but the `print_r($datesArray);` actually outputs the desired result

Comment: Yes their was no return

Comment: I had figured out the same functionality with another way so its ok, but this is interesting to find that code example you've added seems to be working but in actual integration it does not print anything i mean just blank (print_r).

Comment: Well it should be working, can you show the code that is not working ?